# ACF Post Content validation

Tags: wordpress, validation, advanced-custom-fields

I wanted to limit the number of characters for post content.

I tried the code below but the $value is always empty.
post content is using wysiwyg_tinymce

```
    add_filter('acf/validate_value/name=_post_content', 'my_acf_validate_pcontent_value', 10, 4);
    function my_acf_validate_pcontent_value($valid, $value, $field, $input_name) { 
       if(trim($value)=='') { 
           return  __('The description cannot be empty.');
       }    elseif(strlen($value)>200) { 
           return  __('The description cannot be more than 200 characters.');
       }
       return $valid;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct name? Is it inside another ACF field, group, repeater, etc? You can use `acf/validate_value/key={$key}` which would allow you to target the correct element everytime, no matter if it's inside another ACF field

Comment: It's not a field in acf, it's the post content of the post.